# Render image in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Help me please with the next issue. In component OpportTemplate I pass an array as **this.props.children**. It looks like:

```
class WhatOpport extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let opportsArray = [
        {
            imgSrc : '/tasky/src/Assets/images/opportList.png',
            text : 'Создавать список дел по каждому из проектов'
        },

        {
            imgSrc : '/tasky/src/Assets/images/opportExp.png',
            text : 'Сравнивать фактические расходы с расчетными'
        },

        {
            imgSrc : '/tasky/src/Assets/images/opportTeam.png',
            text : 'Создать команды из сотрудников для общего ведения заказа'
        }
    ];
    this.state = {opports : opportsArray};
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="whatOpportWrapper">
            <h1>Tasky предоставляет возможность</h1>
            <div className="opportInsideWrapper row">
                {
                    this.state.opports.map(function(item, i) {
                        return(
                            <OpportTemplate key={i}>{item}</OpportTemplate>
                        );
                    })
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default WhatOpport;
```

In **src** in tag **img** I pass **this.props.children.imgSrc**. 
The images are not rendered like they are not found but in a console I can see their paths which I passed.

```
class OpportTemplate extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div className="col-sm">
            <div className="imgWrapper">
                <img src={this.props.children.imgSrc} alt="img" />
            </div>

            <div className="textWrapper">
                {this.props.children.text}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: You can't use relative paths to local files in image tags or anywhere else in html or javascript due to security considerations. Your javascript code has no filesystem access.

Comment: Ok, I understood you. So what advice can you give me about that?

Comment: server.get('/yourimage.jpg', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'static', 'yourimage.jpg'));
    });

You could do this for all images but really not ideal. Host your images somewhere and add that domain to a config so you could do something like

const image = \`${config.get('IMAGE_DOMAIN')/${item.imgSrc}\`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this. Sorry if i do not get what you want

```
class OpportTemplate extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-sm">
        <div className="imgWrapper">
          <img src={this.props.children.imgSrc} alt="img" />
        </div>

        <div className="textWrapper">
          {this.props.children.text}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let opportsArray = [
      {
        imgSrc: '../../../Assets/images/opportList.png',
        text: 'bla'
      },

      {
        imgSrc: '../../../Assets/images/opportExp.png',
        text: 'blabla'
      },

      {
        imgSrc: '../../../Assets/images/opportTeam.png',
        text: 'blablabla'
      }
    ];
    this.state = { opports: opportsArray };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.renderChild()
    );
  }

  renderChild() {
    return this.state.opports.map((opport) => {
      return <OpportTemplate children={opport} />
    });
  }
}
```